# How to return ReactNode instead of void?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am following this documention to have two different Layout in my Next.js app.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

I try to convert the `_app.js` to `_app.tsx`, but got an error when running `yarn build`. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

I was inspired from this document also how Redux Persist on client side works: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper

```
./pages/_app.tsx:40:11
Type error: Type '({ store }: ReactReduxContextValue<any, AnyAction>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: ReactReduxContextValue<any, AnyAction>) => ReactNode'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

  38 |         </Head>
  39 |         <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
> 40 |           {({ store }) => {
     |           ^
  41 |             <PersistGate
  42 |               persistor={store.__persistor}
  43 |               loading={<div>Loading..</div>}
```

```js
// _app.tsx

import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { useStore, ReactReduxContext } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import Head from "next/head";
import CookieDialog from "../components/CookieDialog";
import FooterDesktop from "../components/FooterDesktop";
import FooterMobile from "../components/FooterMobile";
import styles from "../styles/Layout.module.css";
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout =
    Component.getLayout ||
    ((page) => (
      <>
        <Head>
          <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        </Head>
        <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
          {({ store }) => {
            <PersistGate
              persistor={store.__persistor}
              loading={<div>Loading..</div>}
            >
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </PersistGate>;
          }}
        </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
        <CookieDialog />
        <div className={styles.footerDesktop}>
          <FooterDesktop />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.footerMobile}>
          <FooterMobile />
        </div>
      </>
    ));

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try:

```
{({ store }) => {
        return something
      }}
```

or

```
 { ({ store }) =>  something }
```

arrow function:
()=> { return 1  }    vs   ()=> 1   are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the curly braces, you are actually not returning anything. Change them to parantheses or add the `return` keyword. This will most probably fix the issue.

```js
<ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
{({ store }) => ( // Change curly braces to parantheses
    <PersistGate
    persistor={store.__persistor}
    loading={<div>Loading..</div>}
    >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </PersistGate>;
)}
</ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
```